# How to register UserManager with IdentityServerServiceFactory?

Tags: asp.net-identity, identityserver3

I am using IdentityServer3 for authentication with `AspnetIdentity` for user storage. I have `ApplicationUserManager` class which has `static Create` method that configures UserValidator,PasswordValidator, IdentityTokenProvider etc and returns the instance of `ApplicationUserManager` class

**ApplicationUserManager**

```
public class ApplicationUserManager : UserManager<ApplicationUser, string>
{
    public ApplicationUserManager(ApplicationUserStore store)
        : base(store)
    {
    }

    public static ApplicationUserManager Create(IdentityFactoryOptions<ApplicationUserManager> options, IOwinContext context)
    {
        var manager = new ApplicationUserManager(new ApplicationUserStore(context.Get<ApplicationDbContext>()));

        // Configure validation logic for usernames
        manager.UserValidator = new UserValidator<ApplicationUser>(manager)
        {
            AllowOnlyAlphanumericUserNames = false,
            RequireUniqueEmail = true
        };

        // Configure validation logic for passwords
        manager.PasswordValidator = new PasswordValidator
        {
            RequiredLength = 6,
            RequireNonLetterOrDigit = true,
            RequireDigit = true,
            RequireLowercase = true,
            RequireUppercase = true,
        };

        manager.EmailService = new EmailService();
        var dataProtectionProvider = options.DataProtectionProvider;
        if (dataProtectionProvider != null)
        {
            manager.UserTokenProvider =
                new DataProtectorTokenProvider<ApplicationUser>(dataProtectionProvider.Create("ASP.NET Identity"));
        }
        return manager;
      }
    }
```

How do i register `ApplicationUserManager`'s static Create method with `IdentityServerServiceFactory` so that it can use single instance per request.

```
    public static IdentityServerServiceFactory Configure(this IdentityServerServiceFactory factory, string connectionString)
    {
        factory.UserService = new Registration<IUserService, UserService>();

        // ????? HOW do I Register ApplicationUserManager's static Create method. ???
        // ????? The line below will not configure Validators, IdentityTokenProvider, EmailService etc ?????
        factory.Register(new Registration<ApplicationUserManager>());

        factory.Register(new Registration<ApplicationUserStore>());
        factory.Register(new Registration<ApplicationDbContext>(resolver => new ApplicationDbContext(connectionString)));

        return factory;
    }
```

**UPDATE 1**
I will try to explain my core problem here. We have 3  VS applications for whole identity solution.

1> **Identity Server**: This is the identityserver3 used only for authentication.

2> **Admin Portal**: This application is accessible to only developers/administrators to manage users, clients, scopes. This is VS solution which that combines [IdentityServer3.Admin](https://github.com/IdentityServer/IdentityServer3.Admin) and [IdentityManager](https://github.com/IdentityManager/IdentityManager)

3>**Client Portal**: This application is accessible to end user where user can reset password, change password. This is standard VS ASP.NET MVC5 Application.

All 3 applications shares same entities like `ApplicationUser`, `ApplicationUserStore`, `ApplicationDbContext`, `ApplicationRole`, `ApplicationUserManager` etc etc.

My concern was with `ApplicationUserManager` which is configured with `EmailService`, `UserTokenProvider`, `PasswordValidator` via `Create` method.
All 3 applications shares `ApplicationUserManager` and use it for different pupose.

**AdminPortal:** This application creates new users so it must follow password & username requirements. So I need to register `ApplicationUserManager` with it's create method with `IdentityManagerServiceFactory`. Again How do I do that?

**ClientPortal:** This is where user reset & change password. It must follow password requirements, also it needs EmailService & UserTokenProvider. Since this is standard VS MVC application. I can register `ApplicationUserManager` with its Create method with `OWIN` context
`app.CreatePerOwinContext<ApplicationUserManager>(ApplicationUserManager.Create);`

**IdentityServer:** Here I don't know if its enough to register `ApplicationUserManager` with default constructor (default constructor will not configure validators, UserTokenProvider, EmailService).
or does IdentityServer also needs same PasswordValidator, UserNameValidator, UserTokenProvider, EmailSerice that I used while creating the user?

Comment: I've got the same question. Do you have found a solution to your problem?
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41242738/setup-custom-usermanager-with-asp-net-identity-in-identityserver

Answer (score 1):

I guess following should work

```
factory.Register(new Registration<ApplicationUserManager>(resolver => ApplicationUserManager.Create(options,context)));
```

If you need to pass other registered services(e.g a logger) as parameters to your 'Create' method you can resolve them as follows

```
new Registration<ApplicationUserManager>(resolver =>
    ApplicationUserManager.Create(options,context,resolver.Resolve<ICustomLogger>())
);
```

Refer the following for more details about the identity server DI https://identityserver.github.io/Documentation/docsv2/advanced/di.html

**Update 1**

After reading your update, I think you have not configured identity server with asp.net identity. AFAIK you just cant plug existing ApplicationUserManager with identity server. You have to create custom user service where you can plug any user management system. Most common custom user service implementations are

1. ASP.NET Identity -  ([Implementation](https://github.com/IdentityServer/IdentityServer3.AspNetIdentity)) -  ([Usage](https://github.com/IdentityServer/IdentityServer3.Samples/tree/master/source/AspNetIdentity))
2. Membership Reboot - ([Implementation](https://github.com/IdentityServer/IdentityServer3.MembershipReboot))  - ([Usage](https://github.com/IdentityServer/IdentityServer3.Samples/tree/master/source/MembershipReboot))

Using the first implementation(i.e AspNetIdentity) you should be able to setup your identity server to work with your existing user database and existing `ApplicationUser` related classes.

Comment: I'm assuming you have correctly configured asp.net identity with idenitty server. if not have a look at https://github.com/IdentityServer/IdentityServer3.Samples/tree/master/source/AspNetIdentity

Comment: Why do I need to pass logger when `Create` method is not even using it.  Also you are passing `options` and `context`, how are you getting those 2 parameters?

Comment: logger is just an example. You can either pass services directly as I passed `options` and `context` or you can resolve them using DI as I resolve `logger`.

Comment: I have configured custom user service. See my configure extension method above. and yes I am using AspNetIdentity. Also note that everything is workine fine. I my question was when I configure `ApplicationUserManager` in IndentityServer does it need to configure same passwordvalidator, username validator, UserTokenProvider etc that was used while creating user?

Comment: AFAIK no. `password validator`, `username validator` or `token provider` are not required for identity server as `create user` and `password reset` are not the functionalities that identity server should provide. They should be handled independently from identity server like you do in your AdminPortal. What identity server does is authentication of users and supporting open-id connect flows.