# Setup custom usermanager with asp net identity in identityserver

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5, identityserver3

I used the [aspnet identity sample project](https://github.com/IdentityServer/IdentityServer3.Samples/tree/master/source/AspNetIdentity) as reference. But it looked me better to make seperate client for account maintenance. This because Brock Allen answered a question about changing passwords that this should be in a separate client (see https://vimeo.com/154172925 in the end).

So now i'm not really sure how to setup the usermanager. In the sample project a new usermanager is created but without any `PasswordValidator` or `lockout` settings. I can set those options in the constructor of the usermanger so the `factory.Register(new Registration<UserManager>());` in the `UserService` will use it.
But when I look at a default asp net MVC 5 application, a `public static UserManager Create(IdentityFactoryOptions<UserManager> options, IOwinContext context)` method is used to setup the `PasswordValidator` and `DataProtectionProvider` etc.

I'm not really sure how to setup the `DataProtectionProvider` without that function. Because if understand that correctly, it is needed for email and password verification.

For extra information. This is the default method generated by a MVC 5 application:

```
public static UserManager Create(IdentityFactoryOptions<UserManager> options, IOwinContext context)
{
    var manager = new UserManager(new UserStore(context.Get<Context>()));

    // Configure validation logic for usernames
    manager.UserValidator = new UserValidator<User>(manager)
    {
        AllowOnlyAlphanumericUserNames = false,
        RequireUniqueEmail = true
    };

    // Configure validation logic for passwords
    manager.PasswordValidator = new PasswordValidator
    {
        RequiredLength = 6,
        RequireNonLetterOrDigit = true,
        RequireDigit = true,
        RequireLowercase = true,
        RequireUppercase = true,
    };

    // Configure user lockout defaults
    manager.UserLockoutEnabledByDefault = true;
    manager.DefaultAccountLockoutTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(5);
    manager.MaxFailedAccessAttemptsBeforeLockout = 5;

    // Register two factor authentication providers. This application uses Phone and Emails as a step of receiving a code for verifying the user
    // You can write your own provider and plug it in here.
    manager.RegisterTwoFactorProvider("Phone Code", new PhoneNumberTokenProvider<User>
    {
        MessageFormat = "Your security code is {0}"
    });
    manager.RegisterTwoFactorProvider("Email Code", new EmailTokenProvider<User>
    {
        Subject = "Security Code",
        BodyFormat = "Your security code is {0}"
    });
    ////manager.EmailService = new EmailService();
    ////manager.SmsService = new SmsService();
    var dataProtectionProvider = options.DataProtectionProvider;
    if (dataProtectionProvider != null)
    {
        manager.UserTokenProvider =
            new DataProtectorTokenProvider<User>(dataProtectionProvider.Create("ASP.NET Identity"));
    }

    return manager;
}
```

Comment: have you found answer to this question?

Comment: No I haven't. Is actually stopped with this project because we started again from scratch in dotnet core and IdentityServer4. The user management is now done in the same project as IdentityServer4. The reason is that we got more problems with this separation than it solved problems.

Comment: Thanks. I found the answer and updated my post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42563647/how-to-register-applicationusermanager-with-identityserver-di-framework