# How to register ApplicationUserManager with IdentityServer DI framework?

Tags: asp.net-identity, asp.net-identity-2, identityserver3

I am using IdentityServer3 for authentication. All users are stored in Sql DB so I am also using `Microsoft.AspNet.Identity` framework for actual authentication, and for the same purpose i have created my own `ApplicationUserManager` class.

The AspNet identity has IoC feature integrated into OWIN middleware.  and it registers the `ApplicationUserManager` like:

```
 app.CreatePerOwinContext<ApplicationUserManager>(ApplicationUserManager.Create);
```

it takes function delegate which returns a new instance of a `ApplicationUserManager`

```
public static ApplicationUserManager 
Create(IdentityFactoryOptions<ApplicationUserManager> options,
        IOwinContext context)
    {
        var manager = new ApplicationUserManager(new UserStore<ApplicationUser>(context.Get<ApplicationDbContext>()));
```

However, IdentityServer uses its own DI framework and (*i think*) we cannot use static `Create()` method to rgister `ApplicationUserManager` with IdentityServer, Also `Create()` method takes `IdentityFactoryOptions` and a `IOwinContext` as parameters.

I followed this [SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24391885/how-to-plug-my-autofac-container-into-asp-net-identity-2-1) and i change the implementation of `ApplicationUserManager` to use Constructor Injection

```
public class ApplicationUserManager : UserManager<ApplicationUser, string>
{   
    public ApplicationUserManager(ApplicationUserStore store, IdentityFactoryOptions<ApplicationUserManager> options)
        : base(store)
    {          
        // Configure validation logic for usernames
        UserValidator = new UserValidator<ApplicationUser>(this)
        {
            AllowOnlyAlphanumericUserNames = false,
            RequireUniqueEmail = true
        };

        // Configure validation logic for passwords
        PasswordValidator = new PasswordValidator
        {
            RequiredLength = 6,
            RequireNonLetterOrDigit = true,
            RequireDigit = true,
            RequireLowercase = true,
            RequireUppercase = true,
        };

        // Configure user lockout defaults
        UserLockoutEnabledByDefault = true;
        DefaultAccountLockoutTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(5);
        MaxFailedAccessAttemptsBeforeLockout = 5;

        EmailService = new EmailService();
        SmsService = new SmsService();

        var dataProtectionProvider = options.DataProtectionProvider;
        if (dataProtectionProvider != null)
        {
            UserTokenProvider =
                new DataProtectorTokenProvider<ApplicationUser>(dataProtectionProvider.Create("ASP.NET Identity"));
        }
    }        
}
```

And then register all the services with IdentityServer's own DI framework as below

```
factory.UserService = new Registration<IUserService, UserService>();
factory.Register(new Registration<ApplicationUserManager>());
factory.Register(new Registration<ApplicationUserStore>());
factory.Register(new Registration<IdentityFactoryOptions<ApplicationUserManager>>(resolver => new IdentityFactoryOptions<ApplicationUserManager>
            {
                DataProtectionProvider = new Microsoft.Owin.Security.DataProtection.DpapiDataProtectionProvider("ASP.NET Identity")
            }));
factory.Register(new Registration<ApplicationDbContext>(resolver => new ApplicationDbContext(ApplicationConfig.ConnectionString)));
```

**Questions**

1. Is this a correct way of registering `ApplicationUserManager` with
   IdentiServer's DI framework?
2. I am creating `DataProtectionProvider` during the registration and the `UserTokenProvider` inside the constructor. How this 2 providers are being used by IdentityServer?
3. Note that im not registering `IOwinContext` anywhere since
   ApplicationUserManager's constructor does not need it anymore, will
   that cause any issue down the OWIN pipeline?.
4. What would be ideal registration mode for `ApplicationUserManager`?

Comment: This will help: http://tech.trailmax.info/2014/09/aspnet-identity-and-ioc-container-registration/

Comment: @trailmax after posting my question, i read your article http://tech.trailmax.info/2014/06/asp-net-identity-and-cryptographicexception-when-running-your-site-on-microsoft-azure-web-sites/  since i was also getting CryptographicException. So i register IDataProtectionProvider as `internal static` in Startup.cs as per the suggestion. However my `ApplicationUserManager` is in different assembly so i had to register `IDataProtectionProvider` as `factory.Register(new Registration<IDataProtectionProvider>(resolver => Startup.DataProtectionProvider));`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

These two articles helped to solve my issue

http://tech.trailmax.info/2014/06/asp-net-identity-and-cryptographicexception-when-running-your-site-on-microsoft-azure-web-sites/

http://tech.trailmax.info/2014/09/aspnet-identity-and-ioc-container-registration/

However my `ApplicationUserManager` is in separate class library and `startup.cs` is in web project. The class library does not have reference to the web project. So i refactored `ApplicationUserManager` Constructor

```
    public ApplicationUserManager(ApplicationUserStore store, IDataProtectionProvider dataProtectionProvider)
        : base(store)
    {
       // other stuff


        if (dataProtectionProvider != null)
        {
            UserTokenProvider =
                new DataProtectorTokenProvider<ApplicationUser>(dataProtectionProvider.Create("UserToken"));
        }
    }
```

and also registered `IDataProtectionProvider`  with DI framework. I am not using Unity as IoC. I am using IdentityServer's own DI framework. So i register `IDataProtectionProvider` as

```
  factory.Register(new Registration<IDataProtectionProvider>(resolver => Startup.DataProtectionProvider));
```

Comment: ah, the good old project separation that gets you every time! Good that you have it sorted!