# Entity Framework query throws 'async error' after many requests

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework, asynchronous, asp.net-identity

In my project using .NET framework 4.6.1, EF 6.1.4 and IdentityServer3, I set the following DbContext:

```
public class ValueContext : DbContext
{
    public IValueContext(bool lazyLoadingEnabled = false) : base("MyConnectionString")
    {
        Database.SetInitializer<IValueContext>(null);
        Configuration.LazyLoadingEnabled = lazyLoadingEnabled;
    }

    public DbSet<NetworkUser> NetworkUser { get; set; }
    public DbSet<User> User { get; set; }

[...]
```

And my Entity model `User`:

```
[Table("shared.tb_usuarios")]
public class NetworkUser
{
    [Column("id")]
    [Key()]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [StringLength(255)]
    [Column("email")]
    public string Email { get; set; }

    [...]
    public virtual Office Office { get; set; }
    [...]
```

So far I think its all good.

Then I set this following query in my `UserRepository` (using DI)

```
    protected readonly ValueContext Db;
    public RepositoryBase(ValueContext db)
    {
        Db = db;
    }

    public async Task<ImobUser> GetUser(string email)
    {
        //sometimes I get some error here
        return await Db.User.AsNoTracking()
          .Include(im => im.Office)
          .Include(off => off.Office.Agency)
          .Where(u => u.Email == email &&
                      u.Office.Agency.Active)
          .FirstOrDefaultAsync();
    }
```

And everything runs well, until it starts to get **many sequential requests**, then I begin to get these type of errors, randomly in any function that uses my `ValueContext` as data source:

> System.NotSupportedException: 'A second operation started on this context before a previous asynchronous operation completed. Use 'await' to ensure that any asynchronous operations have completed before calling another method on this context. Any instance members are not guaranteed to be thread safe.'

This is my last hope, as I tried a bunch of different things. Some of them work, and some dont, like:

- Convert dbContext to use DI: no difference.
- Use [context lifetime](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/ef6/fundamentals/working-with-dbcontext#lifetime) to run the queries: works, but isnt the solution I want.
- Remove asyncronous from requests: works, but also I feel is not the correct way to do.

What Im doing wrong?

*EDIT 1*

This is how I set up DI in `Startup.cs`:

```
 private void AddAuth()
 {            
        Builder.Map("/identity", app =>
        {
            var factory = new IdentityServerServiceFactory()
            {
               //here I implemented the IdentityServer services to work
               ClientStore = new Registration<IClientStore>(typeof(ClientStore)),
               [...]
            };

            AddDependencyInjector(factory);
        }

        [...]

}

private void AddDependencyInjector(IdentityServerServiceFactory factory)
{     
      //here I inject all the services I need, as my DbContext       
      factory.Register(new Registration<ValueContext>(typeof(ValueContext)));
      [...]

}
```

And this is how my `UserService` is working:

```
 public class UserService : IUserService
 {

    [Service injection goes here]
    
    //this is a identityServer method using my dbContext implementation on UserRepository
    public async Task AuthenticateLocalAsync(LocalAuthenticationContext context)
    {
    
        SystemType clientId;
        Enum.TryParse(context.SignInMessage.ClientId, true, out clientId);
        switch (clientId)
        {               
            case 2:
                result = await _userService.GetUser(context.UserName);
                break;
            case 3:
                //also using async/await correctly
                result = await _userService.Authenticate(context.UserName, context.Password);
                break;
            default:
                result = false;
                break;
        }

        if (result)
            context.AuthenticateResult = new AuthenticateResult(context.UserName, context.UserName);
   }
```

Comment: Would it be easy for you to attempt inject/send in the connection string and create the context for each call of GetUser() and see if your issue goes away -> using (new ValueContext()){}?

Comment: @RossBush as I mentioned before, I tried this approach, but I think isnt the correct way to do, as now I create a dbContext instance for each query instead a dbContext for each http request

Comment: The problem will be in the calling code.  For instance not `awaiting` GetUser() or similar.

Comment: is the DB context (or underlying connection) ending up being shared between multiple concurrent requests? because: that won't work; so: could it be being shared somehow?

Comment: @DavidBrowne-Microsoft Im always *awaiting* these calls all the way up to `IUserService` from `IdentityServer3`

Comment: The problem is that you are not showing the caller code, two different callers awaiting a response from two different origins will not know about each other, if you try to maintain a singleton context on the server it will fail very frequently

Comment: @MarcGravell teorically no, because the container should create a instance for each request.

Comment: @outrowender well, where/how is that coming from? we can't see the lifetime from here

Comment: This code itself is not enough to reproduce the issue, you need to show us where you have configured DI or where the context gets created and passed into the repository.

Comment: @ChrisSchaller @MarcGravell I`ll try to inspect the caller, because is inside IdentityServer code. I just implemented as the docs says.
I will be back in a few minutes.

Comment: @outrowender the problem is in the code you didn't post. A DbContext can't be used by multiple threads. It's not a long-lived connection to the database, it's a short-lived Unit-of-Work. *No* .NET class would keep a DbContext or a Connection open for long, because that breaks the Unit-of-Work semantics, disconnected operations and optimistic concurrency. Somehow, somewhere, your code keeps a DbContext alive for longer than it should

Comment: @outrowender post the *full* exception text, ie the string returned by `Exception.ToString()` or by copying the `Copy Details` in the exception popup. This includes the stack trace which shows *which* chain of calls caused the exception.

Comment: @outrowender if you registered the `Repository` as a `Singleton`, multiple concurrent requests would try to use the single-threaded DbContext, resulting in this exception. Even without concurrent requests, the DbContext would already be broken. A DbContext is a Unit-of-Work and tracks all changes. If you try to call `SaveChanges` in response to a single `Add` you'll end up persisting *all* previous modifications you though were discarded. That's not a DbContext bug. That's a bug in the code and a consequence of using a "Repository" over the higher-level DbContext

Comment: @outrowender `as now I create a dbContext instance for each query instead a dbContext for each http reques` actually, that's *exactly* how DbContext is meant to be used. That's exactly why `AddDbContext` registers DbContexts as Scoped services. If you don't call `SaveChanges`, all changes are discarded as soon as the request ends and the DbContext is disposed

Comment: @ChrisSchaller  I added some details of the full implementation

Comment: and @MarcGravell I added some details of the full implementation

Comment: @outrowender unless `factory.Register(new Registration<ValueContext>(typeof(ValueContext)));` registers a transient or scoped service, you have a critical bug. Your application will never work correctly. Even if you have so few requests that you avoid threading issues, a single `Repository.Insert` will easily perform 42 pending DELETEs and 17 UPDATEs you though were discarded. A DbContext is meant to be *shot*-lived, typically created in a `using` block

Comment: @outrowender check Gunnar Peipman's [No need for Repositories and Unit-of-Work with Entity Framework Core](https://gunnarpeipman.com/ef-core-repository-unit-of-work/) to see how unnecessary and dangerous  is this code. The article doesn't cover the scaleability problems this "repository" causes either - to get back the UoW you lost by using a long-lived DbContext, you'll have to use a transaction. That in turn means a long-lived collection, accumulated locks, blocking and deadlocks. It's back to the mid-1990s, before VB and ADO introduced disconnected recordsets,

Comment: You need to post your `IdentityServerServiceFactory`  that will likely show us what we need to see, you DI is not setup quite right, the `ValueContext` needs to also be resolved correctly

Comment: Also which of the sample projects are you basing your implementation from, TBO your attempted implementation is hard to follow: https://github.com/IdentityServer/IdentityServer3.Samples

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Update - After code posted

When using ASP.Net DI and IdentityServer DI together, we have to be careful to make sure that both the IdentityServer and the underlying DbContext are scoped to the OWIN request context, we do that by Injecting the DbContext into the IdentityServer context. this answer has some useful background: https://stackoverflow.com/a/42586456/1690217

I suspect all you need to do is resolve the DbContext, instead of explicitly  instantiating it:

```
private void AddDependencyInjector(IdentityServerServiceFactory factory)
{     
      //here I inject all the services I need, as my DbContext       
      factory.Register(new Registration<ValueContext>(resolver => new ValueContext()));
      [...]

}
```

---

### Supporting dicussion, largely irrelevant now...

With EF it is important to make sure that there are no concurrent queries against the same `DbContext` instance at the same time. Even though you have specified `AsNoTracking()` for this endpoint *there is no indication that this endpoint is actually the culprit.* The reason for synchronicity is so that the context can manage the original state, there are many internals that are simply not designed for multiple concurrent queries, including the way the database connection and transactions are managed.

*(under the hood the DbContext will pool and re-use connections to the database if they are available, but ADO.Net does this for us, it happens at a lower level and so is **NOT** an argument for maintaining a singleton DbContext)*

> As a safety precaution, the context will actively block any attempts to re-query while an existing query is still pending.

EF implements the *Unit-Of-Work* pattern, you are only expected to maintain the same context for the current operation and should dispose of it when you are done. It can be perfectly acceptable to instantiate a `DbContext` scoped for a single method, you could instantiate multiple contexts if you so need them.

> There is some anecdotal advice floating around the web based on previous versions of EF that suggest there is a heavy initialization sequence when you create the context and so they encourage the singleton use of the EF context. This advice worked in non-async environments like WinForms apps, but it was never *good* advice for entity framework.

When using EF in a HTTP based service architecture, the correct pattern is to create a new context for each HTTP request and not try to maintain the context or state between requests. You can manually do this in each method if you want to, however DI can help to minimise the plumbing code, just make sure that the HTTP request gets a *new* instance, and not a shared or recycled one.

> Because most client-side programming can create multiple concurrent HTTP requests (this of a web site, how many concurrent requests might go to the same server for a single page load) it is a frivolous exercise to synchronise the incoming requests, or introduce a blocking pattern to ensure that the requests to the `DbContext` are synchronous or queued.

The overheads to creating a new context instance are expected to be minimal and the DbContext is expected to be used in this way especially for HTTP service implementations, so don't try to fight the EF runtime, work with it.

### Repositories and EF

When you are using a repository pattern over the top of EF... (IMO an antipattern itself) it is important that each new instance of the repository gets its own unique instance of the `DbContext`. Your repo should function the same if you instead created the DbContext instance from scratch inside the Repo init logic. The only reason to pass in the context is to have DI or another common routine to pre-create the DbContext instance for you.

> Once the DbContext instance is passed into the Repo, we lose the ability to maintain synchronicity of the queries against it, this is an easy *pain point* that should be avoided.
> No amount of `await` or using synchronous methods on the DbContext will help you if multiple repos are trying to service requests at the same time against the same `DbContext`.

Comment: You should probably mention that `AddDbContext` registers DbContexts as Scoped so they can be disposed immediately after a request ends. Gunnar Peipman's [No need for Repositories and Unit-of-Work with Entity Framework Core](https://gunnarpeipman.com/ef-core-repository-unit-of-work/) also mentions that a typical `Repository`'s `Insert` can end up executing 42 DELETEs and 17 UPDATEs as well, because that `SaveChanges` call persisted all previous changes

Comment: OPs issue here though is that this is EF FX, not core, so its getting harder to track down good FX advice.

Comment: This particular problem is the same with all ORMs (or at least, the full-featured ones). The problem would be the same with NHibernate. In fact, [Repository is the new singleton](https://ayende.com/blog/3955/repository-is-the-new-singleton) was written in 2009 by Oren Eini, the maintainer of NHibernate at the time. [Architecting in the pit of doom: The Evils of the Repository Abstraction Layer](https://ayende.com/blog/4784/architecting-in-the-pit-of-doom-the-evils-of-the-repository-abstraction-layer) is from 2011

Comment: Thanks @PanagiotisKanavos I truly do not understand why anyone tries to use Repository  over UOW but to use repo over the top of an existing UOW is just asking for trouble,

Comment: Because in the last 10 years people forgot or never learned how things work and just use "Best Practices", thinking that will result in a "good" architecture. . Because some authors and presenters have made careers pushing Repositories especially in DDD and would never admit they were wrong or worse, try to explain that the DDD Repository is *not* the same as the "generic" repository. This would muddle the book or presentation and meet resistance from the audience